# langchain SELF_ASK_WITH_SEARCH can't return time and date?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

When I use ask and search tool with google and openai, I always got some placeholders for time and date. The code looks like this:

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
search = GoogleSearchAPIWrapper()
tools = [
    Tool(
        name="Intermediate Answer",
        func=search.run,
        description="useful for when you need to ask with search"
    )
]
self_ask_with_search = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.SELF_ASK_WITH_SEARCH, verbose=True)

query = "What time is it now in chicago?"
self_ask_with_search.run(query)
```

And, the output is:

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
> No.
> So the final answer is: The current time in Chicago is [time].

> Finished chain.
> 'The current time in Chicago is [time].'

If I ask today's date, it returns [date].

Is it a hard coded somewhere for date and time key words?